# PDFKit working on local but on heroku returning blank one page pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, heroku, pdfkit

I have wkhtmltopdf binaries in my bin folder and my initializer is as follows:

```
PDFKit.configure do |config|
  # if ["development"].include?(Rails.env)
  if ENV["TRIPCIPE_ENV"] == "local"
   config.wkhtmltopdf = Rails.root.join('bin', 'wkhtmltopdf').to_s
  else
   config.wkhtmltopdf = Rails.root.join('bin', 'wkhtmltopdf-amd64').to_s
  end  
 end
```

my controller code looks like this

```
html = render_to_string(:action => "pdf", :layout => false)
kit = PDFKit.new(html)
send_data(kit.to_pdf, :filename => 'report.pdf', :type => 'application/pdf', :disposition => 'inline')
```

And it works fine locally but when I deploy on heroku I just get an empty 1 page pdf file.

Any ideas or help would be appreciated, thanks.

I also noticed in my logs it says this:

```
Unable to load library icui18n "Cannot load library icui18n: (icui18n: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)"
```

Anyone seen this before?

UPDATE

So i removed the initializer code and added the gem 'wkhtmltopdf-heroku', which makes the error go away but it's still returning a blank page.